# Issues getting a sum of a field grouped by another field in C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have basic product object that contains an Id, date and sales count. Each product has one object per day with the total sales for that day. I want to be able to accept a date range and return the top selling products between this date.

I am trying to get the sum of sales within a date range but group them by product ID. So that i can get the total sales for product 123, 234,345 etc within the date range and then get back the top 10 best selling products.

This is what I have written. The response doesnt seem to be correct as each product ID has 10 results. I should only be getting 1 value per product ID, which is the total sales. If it were SQL i want to get the sum of sales grouped by product ID.

```
var response = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(s => s
    .Index(this.Index)
    .Query(q => q
        .DateRange(dr => dr
            .Field(drf => drf.Date)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals(startDate)
            .LessThan(endDate)
        )
    )
    .Aggregations(ag => ag
        .Terms("productResults", pr => pr
            .Field(prf => prf.ProductID)
            .Size(10)
            .Aggregations(prag => prag
                .Sum("totalsales", sm => sm
                    .Field(f => f.TotalSales)
                )
            )
            .Order( o => o.Descending("totalsales"))
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Could you add your data structure and the result json to make it easier to help?